# java.lang.InstantiationException Error when try instantiate a children class

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

Hi I have the following clases:

```
public abstract class A(){

    public void doSomething();

    public void makeMe(){
        try {
            A.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumntException
                    | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class B() extends A{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
    }    
}

public class C() extends A{
    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
    }    
}
```

How can do makeMe for that I can get the follow behavior:

```
B.makeMe()

C.makeMe()
```

The original class are more complex than this, this is only an example. But how can get it this, is it possible?

It is possible do this with reflections?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate the abstract class `A`. To instantiate the child class (`B.makeMe()` creates a `B` object and `C.makeMe()` creates a `C` object), replace `A.class` with `this.getClass()`.

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--)